# Why is np.where's result read-only for multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> a = np.where(np.ones(5))[0]
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.flags['WRITEABLE']
True

>>> b = np.where(np.ones((5,2)))[0]
>>> b
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])
>>> b.flags['WRITEABLE']
False
```

Why is `b` read-only while `a` is not?  This is not mentioned in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally numpy computes results in a *one* dimensional array, but then returns a tuple which are *views* with same stride on this array, [one for each dimension](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f896f50fc8b4ad6a38eda286ed0d3d5560759ead/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L2673);

for example, if the array is like this:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [3, 0, 5]])
```

internally numpy first calculates

```
>>> i
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2])
```

where `i[2 * k]` and `i[2 * k + 1]` are the indices of the `k`'th non-zero value; but, then the result that is returned is:

```
>>> (i[::2], i[1::2])
(array([0, 1, 1]), array([1, 0, 2]))
```

when, it creates the view it [passes `0` as the `flags` argument](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f896f50fc8b4ad6a38eda286ed0d3d5560759ead/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L2688). So, the writable flag is unset.

When the input array is one dimensional, [it takes a short-cut](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f896f50fc8b4ad6a38eda286ed0d3d5560759ead/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L2674) and therefore the flags are set differently.

Comment: So it's just the result of how the tuple is created, rather than something that the end user normally needs to know about.  End user don't normally try to modify the results.

Comment: @hpaulj perhaps! from that piece of code, if i am not missing something, i do not see any reason that it should not have writable flag.

Comment: @hpaulj and behzad.nouri: Would you suggest I file a bug report about this?

Comment: Nice digging into the guts of the source code! This is very likely an unintended behavior. `PyArray_New` treats the flags parameter very differently when you pass a pointer to the data and when you do not, see[here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.9.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L977). The proper thing to do, it seems to me, would be to copy the flags from the array being viewed. So yes, I think this is worth a bug report!

Answer (score 1):

The `__array_interface__` gives evidence that the elements of `b` are views:

```
In [335]: b[0].__array_interface__
Out[335]: 
{'shape': (10,),
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'strides': (8,),
 'version': 3,
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'data': (145873656, True)}

In [336]: b[1].__array_interface__
Out[336]: 
{'shape': (10,),
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'strides': (8,),
 'version': 3,
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'data': (145873660, True)}
```

The shape and strides are the same.  The data pointer differs by 4 bytes.  That's what one would expect from views generated by `(i[::2], i[1::2])`.  A strides of `(8,)` means every other integer.

And the internal 2d `ret` array can be 'recreated' with `as_strided`:

```
  In [362]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(b[0],(10,2),(8,4))
Out[362]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [4, 0],
       [4, 1]])
```

The tuple form is most useful for use as an index.  Still it is interesting to know that underlying that tuple is a 2d array.

---

This is a Python replica of the `C` nonzero function (the ndim>1 case).  It's in the last step, written as `tuple(ret.T)` where the readonly views are generated.  As expected this is much slower than the `C` code.  It should be an interesting `cython` adaptation exercise.

```
def nonzero(a):
    nnz = np.count_nonzero(a)
    ndim = a.ndim
    ret = np.zeros((nnz, ndim), dtype=np.intp)
    it = np.nditer(a,flags=['multi_index', 'zerosize_ok', 'refs_ok'],
            op_flags=['readonly'])
    n = 0
    while not it.finished:
        if it.value!=0:
            ret[n] = it.multi_index
            n += 1
        it.iternext()
    # tuple(ret[:,i] for i in range(ndim))
    return tuple(ret.T)
```